# angularjs Strange issue-Google voice search issue with website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, google-voice

I have implemented a website with the help of angularjs,jquery and ruby on rails as back end.

I have also used #! in the url of the website..
Now to make the website crawlable I have used escaped_fragment so as to allow google to crawl.

The website is live for about 15 days now and is quite stable..Now the problem I am having is that when I am using google Voice search and I say `open abc.com website` it is redirecting me to the escaped fragment url for eg:- `www.abc.com?_escaped_fragment_=/Home` whereas it should go to `www.abc.com/#!/Home`

If I try only `open abc` or `abc.com` it is giving me proper results and am redirected to the proper home page ie `www.abc.com/#!/Home`.All the other mobile search are giving me proper results(google search).

Why is this happening and what should I do to stop this.
Is this a bug with google